# PHPSESSID cookies dont get deleted / die

Tags: cookies

I am having dificulty ending the session cookie. whenever i login and logout, the browser still shows the "PHPSESSID".

Below is my code for loging out and destroy session. I have tried on both "Chrome and Firefox" and still same problem.

```
function LogOut()
{
    session_start();

    $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar();

    $_SESSION[$sessionvar]=NULL;

    setcookie("PHPSESSID","",time()-3600,"/"); // delete session cookie 
    session_destroy(); //session destroy

}
```

Comment: What is `$this->GetLoginSessonVar()`? I'm not seeing the method.

Answer (score 0):

cookies cannot be set until the page is redirected or reloaded. You may try sending a header.

Comment: unction LogOut()
{
    session_start();

    $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar();

    $_SESSION[$sessionvar]=NULL;


    session_destroy(); //session destroy

}

Comment: You should `unset($_SESSION[$sessionvar])` as well.